# nHibernate Multiple table mapping with where clause or multipe column mapping

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, orm, mapping, translation

I'm trying to translate a table "RoomType".

I create a "Texts" table that contains:

```
Id, LangID, TranslatedText
001, EN, Single
001, IT, Singola
002, EN, Double
002, IT, Doppia
```

This is the DB Schema
[image]

The table RoomType contains:
ID, TextID, MaxBed
01, 001, 1
02, 002, 2

I need to create an nHibernate Mapping that join RoomType and Text and permit to load RoomType queing Text with WHERE clause on LandID = CurrentLanguage.

This is a little mapping but I do not know how I can go next:

```
public class RoomTypeaMap : ClassMapping<RoomType>
    {
        public RoomTypeaMap()
        {
            Join("Texts", el =>
                {
                    el.Key(k => k.Column("TextID"));
                });
        }
    }
```

**As an alternative I can add a column for every language**

[image]

In this scenario I need that the mapping Gets the localized name of the roomtype from and (preferring) to different column.

Something like this:

```
public class RoomTypeaMap : ClassMapping<RoomType>
    {
        public RoomTypeaMap()
        {
            Property(el => el.Name, m =>
                {
                    m.Formula("Name_" + currentLanguage);
                });
        }
    }
```

I found this interesting post but it not help me:
http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/localization-techniques.aspx

Thank You for your help!!

Comment: The article you linked to contains lots of options. Why didn't it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would get rid of the language table and have the Texts table as Element table for a map

```
public class RoomType
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<string, string> Names { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return Names[Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name]; } // FIXME: fall back to default language if language not available
        set { Names[Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name] = value; }
    }
}
```

and use the folling Mapping

```
public RoomTypeMap()
{
    [...]
    HasMany(mc => mc.Names)
        .Table("Texts")
        .KeyColumn("RoomType_id")
        .AsMap("language_id")
        .Element("value")
```

Update:

to implement the fallback

```
string name;
var currentlanguage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;     // eg en-US
if (!map.TryGetValue(currentlanguage.Name, out result) &&        // en-US
    !map.TryGetValue(currentlanguage.Parent.Name, out result))   // en
{
    result = "fallback name";
}
return name;
```