# FluentNHibernate entity localization

Tags: .net, localization, fluent-nhibernate

First of all I investigated some solutions like [this one](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Localizing-entities-with-NHibernate.aspx)
Now, I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
public class Article : Entity 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public CultureInfo Culture {get;set;}
   public DateTime PublishedOn {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Now here are the facts:

1. ID is unique identifier
2. Culture should distinct different culture versions
3. Title property should be localized (one raw for each culture)
4. PublshDate shouldn't be localized since it is same for all cultures

Now, here is what I need:

1. Use only one class per entty: I don't want "Article" and "ArticleLocal" classes
2. Provide system to let NHibernate to get proper culture raw for entity (based on soem global property fo current culture)
3. If possible, to force NHibernate to create Local table automatically on initialization.

My idea was to use attributes but not sure if there is already proven solution. Here is idea:

```
[LocalizedEntity]
public class Article : Entity 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   [LocalizedCulture("CultureID")]
   public CultureInfo Culture {get;set;}
   public DateTime PublishedOn {get;set;}
   [Localized("Title")]
   public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question pops up from time to time and i would suggest something without too much magic

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495858/671619
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11289016/671619

which has the benefit that implementing fallback and adding localizations is dead easy